# merge dataframes in a function in R

Tags: r

I have the following folder structure,

```
-test1
-test2
-test3
-test4
-test5
```

within those folders there are .tsv files I am able to open via a function i wrote:

```
process <- function(f){
  df <- read.csv(f, sep = "\t", header = F)
  colnames(df) <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")
  df <- df[-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),]
  df <- df[c("1", "7")]
  df <- merge(df, df, by="1") 
  print(df)
}
files <- dir("path", recursive = T, full.names = T, pattern = "*.tsv")
sapply(files, process)
```

this prints the dataframes I need, but what I want to do is automatically merge the dataframes into one, merge on column 1 but the code above does not do as I want, I get the following error:
**Error in as.data.frame(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default**

Comment: What does `merge(df, df, by="1")` do? Also, if you are setting `sep` and `header` in `read.csv` then you should use `read.table` instead. `read.csv` is in fact `read.table` with some defaults set, including `sep=","` and `header=TRUE`, and these defaults cannot be changed. Functions `read.csv` and `read.csv2` are deliberately meant to be inflexible.

Comment: it merges the dataframes based on the values in column 1, thanks for the comment on the read.table, I will remember that for future notice. Would an Idea to fix my issue be: create an empty dataframe in my function and merge the data into that one?

Comment: But it's *only one* df, not *dataframes*, plural. You are just repeating column `"7"`.

Comment: In every folder there is a .tsv files I need to read, and from all these .tsv files column 1 is the same, and column 7 has values I need to have in one big data frame.

Comment: (1) You should be using `lapply` instead of `sapply`, as the latter will try to simplify into an array ... and might succeed, depending on the structure. (2) Do you really need to `print` each frame as it is worked on? That seems a bit noisy, but it still works since it invisibly returns the data itself. (3) *"merge the dataframes into one"* suggests one of (a) `do.call(rbind, lapply(files, process))`; (b) same, but with `cbind`; or (c) `Reduce(function(a, b) merge(a, b, by = ...), lapply(files, process))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. Untested, since there are no data.

```
process <- function(f){
  df <- read.delim(f, header = FALSE)
  colnames(df) <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")
  df <- df[-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),]
  df[c("1", "7")]
}
files <- dir("path", recursive = T, full.names = T, pattern = "\\.tsv$")
df_list <- lapply(files, process)
```

After reading the files into `df_list` the following will merge (join) them by column `"1"` and the result is **wider**.

```
df_final <- Reduce(\(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "1"), df_list)
names(df_final)[-1] <- sprintf("Var%03d", seq_along(names(df_final)[-1]))
```

If instead you want to bind the files by rows, with a **longer** result use

```
df_final <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Or, to know the files where the data comes from, include their names in a new column.

```
df_list2 <- lapply(seq_along(files), \(i) {
  cbind(data.frame(file = files[i]), df_list[[i]])
})
df_final_long <- do.call(rbind, df_list2)
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, I am doing this to 550 files, is it possible they get there own name, like 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. because now they are only called .x and .y.

Comment: @szmple Do you really want the files side by side? If yes, after merging the files try something like `names(df_final)[-1] <- sprintf("Var%03d", seq_along(names(df_final)[-1]))`.

Comment: @szmple I edited the question with the code in the comment and added code for the long format case.

Comment: Your code worked, except for the part how to know where the data comes from, im  trying to include the names of the original files to a new column, but that part is not working.

Comment: @szmple What was the result, can you describe what didn't work?

Comment: I ran it again and it did do as it stated. My issue is solved, thank you very much for answering.